# How are these searches working so fast?

Tags: magento, search

I tend to work with Magento 1 or 2 and their search is quite slow. I want to make it fast and load over ajax, i have had a little luck with Magento 1 making it almost instant but Magento 2 I can barely get it below 1 second.

These sites however are insanely fast and was wondering how this is being done and how to add this functionality within Magento 2?

https://www.allianceonline.co.uk

https://gmsuppliesltd.co.uk

Comment: Which one is Magento 1 or 2?  From my desktop they are BOTH incredibly fast.  Birmingham, AL.  USA  Can you use MySQL to SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  on each system and compare?

Comment: I thinik gmsupplies ltd was Magento 1 not sure of that alliance is. Algolia and similar tech i believe is the trick however.